# Cannot resolve symbol 'FilterQuery'

Tags: java, maven, twitter

I am trying to integrate with twitter api to read tweets and process them for some storm course that I am doing.

I am having trouble in importing FilterQuery class for twitter.4j.

My code is :
        `final FilterQuery query = new FilterQuery();
        //topics
        query.track(new String[]{"chocolate"});`

I have added the maven dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I even tried adding the import manually like :

import twitter4j.FilterQuery;

But no gain.

Can someone help me out with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

twitter4j.FilterQuery is not in twitter4j-core but is in twitter4j-stream.  Try adding a  maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi churd, I had already added twitter4j-stream in my project but i was using 2.2.0. Now when I updated it with the version you mentioned (4.0.4), it worked. I think there was an issue with the version which is fixed now. Thanks.